# Cufon - jQuery, Replace font color on click

Tags: jquery, replace, cufon

I am using cufon for some font replacement and jQuery to build a custom accordion.

the code for my accordion is something like this:

```
 $(".acc-title").click(function () {
   //show something, hide something etc.
 });
```

Is it possible during the click event to change the color of the replaced (with cufon) font?

something like:

```
$(".acc-title").click(function () {
       //some something, hide something etc.
       Cufon.replace('how do i select ONLY the title of this', { color: '#fff' });
});
```

Answer (score 15):

You must use Cufon.refresh(); after you change the color by CSS. Like this:

```
$("#tab1").click(function() {
   $("#tab2").removeClass("selected");
   $("#tab1").addClass("selected");
   Cufon.refresh();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That helped me a lot, I always struggled when I needed to change the font color of cufon text dynamically...

Answer (score 0):

I would be looking at using a CSS class instead of changing the colour through the css function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".acc-title").click(function () {
        $("#cufonid").addClass('cufonCSSClass');
    });
});
```

Although, if you are looking to show/hide:

```
        $("#cufonid").show();
        $("#cufonid").hide();
```

If acc-title is the thing you are operating on, then the following will suffice:

```
    $(".acc-title").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass('cufonCSSClass');
        //or
        $(this).hide();
        //etc, etc
    });
```

You could also speed the above acc-title selector by combining it with the ID of a parent element.

```
    $("#somparentid .acc-title").click(function () {
```

Or give the item an ID itslef:

```
    $("#acc-title").click(function () {
```

Or, your h2 (this is a little slower, though):

```
    $("h2.acc-title").click(function () {
```

So, to summarise, your answer might look something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("h2.acc-title").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass('cufonCSSClass');
    });
});
```

But I'm guessing a bit as I'm not entirely sure what you're after

Comment: it doesn't seem to work. no matter how i reference the item it doesn't change color during an event (click)

Comment: Check that you selectors are getting something, e.g  alert($(yourselector).length); //should be 1 or more